# How do I cast a JSON sub-value to an integer in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, casting

I currently have this

```sql
  UPDATE {$table}
            SET
                {$column} = JSON_SET(
                    {$column},
                    '$.{$jsonKey}',
                    {$column}->>'$.{$jsonKey}' * 100
                )
```

However the value inside the json will be a double. **I would like it to be an integer.**
The code below results in a syntax error.

```sql
 UPDATE {$table}
            SET
                {$column} = JSON_SET(
                    {$column},
                    '$.{$jsonKey}',
                    {$column}->> CAST('$.{$jsonKey}' * 100 AS UNSIGNED)
                )
```

Comment: Do not mix SQL code and pseudocode, please. Post SQL code with some definite parameters values.

Comment: Test `CAST({$column}->> '$.{$jsonKey}' * 100 AS UNSIGNED)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine JSON_EXTRACT with JSON_SET, and then CAST the extracted value to Integer.

```
UPDATE {$table}
SET
    {$column} = JSON_SET(
        {$column},
        '$.{$jsonKey}',
        CAST(JSON_EXTRACT({$column}, '$.{$jsonKey}') * 100 AS UNSIGNED)
    )
```